# bower - Specify folder name in dependency

Tags: bower

I have created a .bowerrc file with this configuration:

```
{
  "directory": "web/",
  "analytics": false,
  "timeout": 120000
}
```

While installing dependency I would like to specify a directory path for each of the dependencies individually. Something like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "directory1/library1": "<git-endpoint-1>",
    "directory2/library2": "<git-endpoint-2>"
  }
```

Bower is not accepting dependencies in this format. How can i overcome this issue?